# Setting up oauth module/login in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, authentication, oauth, drupal-7, facebook-login

I want to allow my users to login from Facebook/Google+/Twitter in a common and secure way. In such a way that the users cannot be spy on. So I think a very common way is to use oauth, but that does not work like I expect.

I don't know how to setup the [oauth module](http://drupal.org/project/oauth) right. I found also the question [How do I configure the Services OAuth sub-module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1077/how-do-i-configure-the-services-oauth-sub-module) but that answer is very old and ends with a "To be continued..." statement.

So far I was able to comprehend that I need to generate a context (http://example.org/admin/config/services/oauth/contexts) and a [oauth connector](http://drupal.org/project/oauthconnector) (http://example.org/admin/structure/oauthconnector). So I think I setted them correctly but I cannot see where the user may access that.

Could you point me to a tutorial or something like that? I'm not able to find the right words to google that myself. Sorry for that!

Comment: I was able to just upload and activate the OAuth module. Nothing else to set it up. I combined it with the Twitter module (which requires the OAuth module: http://drupal.org/project/twitter) and that worked fine. For Facebook, I'm using the Facebook OAuth module.

Comment: maybe check out the Hybridauth module as an alternative. https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth

Comment: As Peter suggested, the Twitter module provides a good example of how to work with the OAuth module. I recommend spinning up a test site and going through the steps outlined in the Twitter module's README file.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal module instructions are usually found on the same module page under the Resources> Read Documentation section. This is one the important tutorials to begin with. So use [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2110825)

Comment: But he asked for Drupal7, and not for 8!